# Macbook White Mid 2007 will not boot even on Mac OS X Lion bootup USB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup

I see the gray screen and nothing shows up for minutes on the screen not even the blinking question marked folder. Does anyone know how to get it to boot as I have a new hard drive I installed and want to install Mac OS X Lion via the time machine backup. The old hard drive works fine but the boot up using the USB stick does not work.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this problem by creating the Bootable USB stick by booting into my old hard drive and downloading and installing the recovery disk on the USB stick. Before I made the bootable USB stick on OS X Yosemite.